# Numeric Up-Down control, detect up or down

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

Is there a way to detect with the Numeric Up-down control to see if the Up or Down button is pressed without coding?

I know I could keep track of the current value and write some code in the method ValueChanged. I was just thinking maybe there is an easier/shorter way to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track specifically the buttons being used and not the value being changed directly you can create your own `UserControl` that inherits from `NumericUpDown` and override the `UpButton()` and `DownButton()` methods. Otherwise if you want to track all value changes, using the `ValueChanged` event is the best way to cover all ways of changing the value, including programatically.